# How many spell slots does a Paladin/Warlock multiclassed character get?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, multi-classing, paladin, spell-slots

I am playing a Level 8 Paladin Warlock Multiclass (5 Paladin / 3 Warlock levels) in DnD 5e. I am little confused over multiclassing with spell slots. If I understood correctly I have 3 first level spell slots from level 5 Paladin (5 levels of paladin divided by 2 rounded down) and 2 second level spell slots from level 3 Warlock. The problem is when I use my Aurora (dnd 5e character builder  application) I have much more spell slots, even 3 third level spell slots. When I searched the internet I saw people get more spell slots from Paladin. How this is possible, can anyone help?

Comment: This should be covered by the marked duplicate. If that Q&A doesn't resolve the question for you, please [edit] this question to explain how it doesn't and/or which parts you don't understand.

Comment: @BayPacman I think the thing that's specifically tripped you up is that warlocks don't have a Spellcasting feature - they have Pact Magic, which is considered separately when multiclassing. You only have Spellcasting from paladin, and therefore have all the spell slots that a 5th level paladin has, plus the Pact Magic spell slots that a 3rd level warlock has (4x1st, 2x2nd, and 2 extra 2nd level slots from Pact Magic). However, there's no way you should have 3rd level spell slots with that build; you'd have to be a 9th level paladin or 5th level warlock. If Aurora says otherwise, it's wrong.

Comment: @Baypacman I'd suggest you might want to try to build your character on DndBeyond - it might be more accurate.